# Google Dataflow: Read unbound PCollection from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, stream-processing

I have a pipeline that streams JSON messages from PubSub (Unbound PCollection) to Google Cloud Storage. Each file should contain multiple JSON objects, one per line.

I want to create another pipeline that should read all the JSON objects from this GCS bucket for further **stream-processing**. The most important thing is that this second pipeline should work as a stream rather than a batch. Means I want it to "listen" to the bucket and process every JSON object written to it. An **Unbound** PCollection.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The streaming process only works with PubSub datasource. But don't worry, you can achieve your pipeline.

- Create [a notification subscription on the bucket to publish event on PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)
- Create a pipeline that listen the PubSub message.

  - When a message arrives, read it and get the file URI
  - Use the storage API to read the file and inject each line in the pipeline
  - Continue your pipeline with each decoded line.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what kind of performance you experience with this approach. I'm taking a similar approach and the beam.io.ReadAllFromText() step seems to be a real bottleneck. The number of workers required to achieve satisfactory throughput isn't viable.

Answer (score 0):

Another user provided a good answer that tells you how to do what you want, however, if I understand your problem correctly, I think I can recommend a cleaner approach.

Assuming the following is true, that you want to:

- Accept a Pub/Sub message at the beginning of your pipeline
- Process the message by windowing it into a big window of messages
- Write each window of messages into a GCS bucket as a file
- In addition to the windowing described above, process each line in another way

Then you can instead create one pipeline that simply forks after the "accept Pub/Sub message" step. Dataflow supports this natively very well. You would save a reference to the `PCollection` object returned when you use the Pub/Sub sink at the beginning of your pipeline. Then, you would apply multiple chains of `DoFn` implementations etc to this one reference. You'll be able to do the windowing with writing to GCS like you do now, plus process each individual message in any way you like.

It might look like this:

```java
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<String> messages = pipeline.apply("Read from Pub/Sub", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic("my_topic_name));

// Current pipeline fork for windowing into GCS
messages.apply("Handle for GCS", ...);

// New fork for more handling
messages.apply("More stuff", ...);
```